# QnA maker bot Not responding in MS Teams

Tags: botframework

We recently added a QnA Maker Bot to MS Teams and got it to Deploy on the Azurewebsites.net/api.  Unfortunately in MS Teams when you direct message the bot it is not responding at all.  We checked the logs and are not getting any errors either.  Any Idea where we need to check next?

Thank you,
M

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this problem, and it was because I was trying to hit the bot directly rather than creating a Teams App first. You will need to install App Studio from the Apps blade on the left if you haven't already.

1. Open up App Studio and click on Manifest editor tab
2. Click Create a new app
3. Fill our all of the required information for App details
4. Generate/create an App ID. This is NOT the same as your Bot's App ID
5. Click on Bots tab under Capabilities and add your bot
6. Install app for testing in specific Teams or Chats

Submit is for if you want to publish to your company's App Store. If you download the package you could import it in Step 2 instead of creating a new app. Or use it as a template to do future apps offline instead of using App Studio for the whole process.

Once I set up the bot in this way, it started responding to me. I tried with another app after doing this for one and confirmed that I would NOT get a response from a bot unless I had set it up with a manifest through App Studio.

Comment: Thank you @billoverton ,  I will try this and comment back to you.

Comment: If this worked please accept the answer! If not please let me know and I will see if I can assist you further.

Comment: @billoverton Your last comment there looks familiar 