# BotFramework Node bot not responding to Teams or Skype

Tags: azure, botframework

I have a Node.js bot linked to a **F0** Bot Service pricing tier that works well with Web Chat, Telegram and Slack channels but not with Microsoft Teams or Skype. The application says nothing on log files when sending messages via Teams and Skype, as if it's not receiving anything. App ID and secret are correct.

What am I missing? It seems to be a setup issue.

Comment: Does the bot have an app manifest.json on Teams? That can sometimes stop Teams communication.

Comment: I don't know about Skype but I answered a similar question here regarding Teams: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105154/qna-maker-bot-not-responding-in-ms-teams/58105614#58105614. As JJ_Wailes mentioned, a manifest is required for the bot to work in teams.